# How can I display both the text fields

Tags: android

I have two activities say A1 and A2, they both have two edit text fields, one for the title and other for the story. When the user enters the text in activity A1, in both of these text fields, and presses the save button, the entry gets saved in a list view. Now when the user again clicks on the entry just saved, the title and the story should be displayed in the title and the story text field of the activity A2. I am getting the title in activity A2, but I can't understand why is the story part not getting displayed.

Here's the code for Activity A1, when the item was clicked.

```
static String title = "";
static String story = "";

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    // here arg3 is the id of the item which is pressed
    registerForContextMenu(arg1);
    id_item_clicked = arg3;
    position_item = arg2;
    Cursor c = (Cursor) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
    title = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DataHolder.KEY_TITLE));
    story = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DataHolder.KEY_STORY));
    Intent i = null;

    // remove this toast later
    Toast.makeText(DiaryActivity.this, "TestClick", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    try {
        i = new Intent(A1.this,
                Class.forName("com.android.project.A2"));
        i.putExtra(ROW_ID, arg3);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    startActivity(i);
}
```

Here's the code for Activity A2, which displays the text in the two text fields:

```
EditText title_read, display_story_read;
private long rowId;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.readdata);

    // bundle receives the row id of the item clicked
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    rowId = extras.getLong("row_id");

    setupVaiables();

    title_read.setText(A1.title);
    display_story_read.setText(A1.story);
}
```

The title is getting displayed, but the story part is not, please help me with this, I've been trying for like hours. And can someone tell me why do I get only a few replies to my questions?

Answer (score 0):

Passing variables in such way is bad practice. You can pass variables via the intent:

```
i.putExtra(TITLE_KEY, title);
i.putExtra(STORY_KEY, story);
```

or get title and story from the database in activity A2, not A1.

Are you sure that story field was written in the DB? Check value of the story that you get, write it in the log or in the toast.

---

Side note: you can construct intent from the class:

```
Intent i = new Intent(A1.this, A2.class);
```

In this case you don't need `try..catch` block.